# WPF UI Automation - AutomationElement.FindFirst fails when there are lots of elements

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

We've got some automated UI tests for our WPF app (.NET 4); these test use the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) API's.

We call [AutomationElement.FindFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findfirst.aspx) to find a target element, and then interact with it.

Example (pseudocode):

```
var nameEquals = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "OurAppWindow");
var appWindow = DesktopWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, nameEquals);
// this succeeds

var idEquals = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "ControlId");
var someItem = appWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, idEquals);
// this suceeds sometimes, and fails sometimes!
```

The problem is, the `appWindow.FindFirst` will sometimes fail and return null, even when the element is present. I've written a helper function which walks the UI automation tree manually and prints it out, and the element with the correct ID is present in all cases.

It seems to be related to how many other items are also being displayed in the window. If there are no other items then it always succeeds, but when there are many other complex UI elements being displayed alongside it, then the find fails.

It appears as though we're hitting some kind of internal element limit. I can't find any documented element limit mentioned for any of the automation API's - is there some way around this? I'm thinking I might have to write my own implemententation of `FindFirst` which does the tree walk manually itself... As far as I can tell this should work, because my tree-printer utility function does exactly that, and it's ok, but it seems like this would be unnecessary and slow :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'am working now since some days with the UI Automation framework and it is really a shame how many bugs I find. It is FULL of bugs on all levels. Microsoft did a very sloppy work. But the bugs seem to be in the server side of the framework because it makes a big difference if you automate a Win32 or a WPF or a .NET Forms application. Depending on the underlying UI framework you get other types of bugs. Additionally many controls are not supported at all or functionality is so basic that you cannot automate them.

Answer (score 2):

Doing the tree walk manually is probably the best way to work around this issue.

And in fact, you'll probably find that an implementation of `FindFirst` using tree walking will be faster that using `FindFirst` on an element with a large number of children. If you look at the code for `AutomationElement.FindFirst` in Reflector, you'll see that it works by pulling accross the automation boundary all children matching the condition, then returning the first of them. By contrast, the TreeWalker approach will only attempt to pull the single first child accross the boundary.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I didn't use any UI automation TreeWalkers though, I just did a recursive `foreach(child in x.children)`. It was slow as heck, so I'll look into using the `TreeWalker` class and see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in one of my Applications I was automating.  I had a custom control that was on the AdornerLayer and I was modifying the UI Automation tree so the Adorner's AutomationElement appeared as a UI Visual child to the control it was decorating instead of appearing as a child of the root for the application.

When I ran UI Spy I would get a number of errors in the Output Window stating things about an invalid parent as I navigated through its tree.  I resolved a bug in my code in how I was parenting the AutomationElement for the Adorner's AutomationElement.  Once I fixed the bug, UI Spy no longer displayed errors in the Output Window and I was no longer getting failures from the FindFirst method calls.

If the original poster is still monitoring this question I would ask does UI Spy have any problems navigating through your Application?

Comment: Where do I get UISpy? I've never been able to find a download for it :-(

Comment: You have to download it through Microsoft as part of an SDK.  Try Here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4377F86D-C913-4B5C-B87E-EF72E5B4E065&displaylang=en and according to someone you only need to select ".NET Development Tools".  I got UISpy from a different full SDK download.

Answer (score 0):

I even stuck with this problem but i only have not seen my failure.

```
var window = new System.Windows.Window();
window.Show();
window.Content = addControl;
GetWindow(window.Name);
```

I create a window an the fly and added the control as the Content of the window. My failure here was, that i showed the window, and then assigned the Content. This even fails. After hours of searching i changed it my code to this:

```
var window = new System.Windows.Window();
window.Content = addControl;
window.Show();
GetWindow(window.Name);
```

... and it works.

Michael

Comment: What a shame! You did not even understand the question!